# Counting rows in different tables and grouping by a certain criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, counting

I have 3 tables: Projects, Components, Suppliers. Each one has an id column, city column and some other columns.

What I am trying to do is count how many projects, components and suppliers there are for each city.

What I have tried is:

```
SELECT p.city, COUNT(p.idp), COUNT(c.idc), COUNT(s.idf) FROM
Projects p, Components c, Suppliers s
GROUP BY p.city
```

After running this query, I am getting incorrect values, almost all of them are the same, like it's shown here:
[image: Results]

I only have one project, 1 or 2 components and 1-3 suppliers stored for each city so these are not the expected results

After looking for some similar solved problems I came up with this piece of code

```
SELECT p.city , p.nr_projects, c.nr_components, s.nr_suppliers
FROM 
(SELECT city, COUNT(idp) AS nr_projects
FROM Projects
GROUP BY city)
AS p
JOIN
(SELECT city, COUNT(idc) AS nr_components
FROM Components
GROUP BY city)
AS c
ON p.city=c.city
JOIN
(SELECT city, COUNT(idf) AS nr_suppliers
FROM Suppliers
GROUP BY city)
as f
ON p.city=f.city
GROUP BY p.city;
```

This gave me an error saying that the SQL command was not properly ended.

How should I approach this task?

Comment: Your problem is the `GROUP BY` in the main query. Delete it. Then, there may be cities missing in one or another of the tables. Use `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of inner joins to get all cities. Full outer joins of multiple tables work best with `USING` instead of `ON` clauses, by the way. What DBMS are you using? Does it support full outer joins? Does it support the using clause?

Comment: Your first query is just horrible. (Sorry.) Comma-separated joins went out of fashion in the early 1990s. You are cross joining three tables here.

Comment: I am using Oracle. I managed to solve the problem by following Nick's advice!

Comment: I am learning SQL now and stumbled upon this task that I didn't manage to accomplish. I know that I may make some beginner mistakes

Comment: Oracle is a very good DBMS. You can use full outer joins with the using clause: `select city, p.nr_projects, c.nr_components, s.nr_suppliers from (...) p full outer join (...) c using (city) full outer join (...) s using (city)`.

Comment: As to learning: Just never use comma-separated joins. Always use explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`). THe `USING` clause is great for multiple full outer joins, otherwise I prefer the `ON` clause. With aggregations it is a good habit to aggregate first and join then. The queries get a bit longer this way sometimes, but their intention is very clear and they are less prone to errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are no longer performing any aggregation at the top level of your query, you no longer need a `GROUP BY` clause. Also, for Oracle, you cannot use an `AS` in the table alias expression. This should work:

```
SELECT p.city , p.nr_projects, c.nr_components, s.nr_suppliers
FROM 
    (SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS nr_projects
    FROM Projects
    GROUP BY city) p
JOIN
    (SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS nr_components
    FROM Components
    GROUP BY city) c ON p.city=c.city
JOIN
    (SELECT city, COUNT(*) AS nr_suppliers
    FROM Suppliers
    GROUP BY city) s ON p.city=s.city
```

Note that if a city might not have projects, components or suppliers then you should use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in place of `JOIN` to ensure you still get rows for that city in the output.

Note also that it is more efficient to use `COUNT(*)` than to count a particular variable (as there is no need to check for `NULL` values) and I have made that modification to the query.

Comment: We need also to change s.nr_suppliers to f.nr_suppliers

Comment: @zip - well spotted. I've changed the table alias as `s` makes more sense than `f`

Comment: I'd prefer `COUNT(*)`in the queries, though. We should only use `COUNT(<expression>)`, if you wanted to exclude nulls from the counting, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Union the totals, then aggregate.

That way you'll also have totals for cities that are missing in 1 of the tables.
Which wouldn't be in the result when using `INNER JOIN`.  (but they would with `FULL JOIN`)

```
SELECT city, 
SUM(proj) AS projects, 
SUM(comp) AS components, 
SUM(supp) AS suppliers
FROM 
(
    SELECT city
    , COUNT(idp) AS proj
    , 0 AS comp
    , 0 AS supp
    FROM Projects
    GROUP BY city

    UNION ALL

    SELECT city, 0, COUNT(idc), 0
    FROM Components
    GROUP BY city

    UNION ALL

    SELECT city, 0, 0, COUNT(idf)
    FROM Suppliers
    GROUP BY city
) q
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY city
```